# Using PHP to assign css/js files to an html document

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, include

I've created my own templating/viewing engine to use with Codeigniter. In it I'm able to specify certain css/js files to use with a specific view. I assign the file names in an array, which will then get looped through while echoing the necessary `<link href="X"..., <script type="X"...,` etc for the respective file type in the header file of the template.

The problem is that I can't seem to use the resources I'm trying to include. The CSS/JS files aren't working even though they're being included and embedded and everything looks right in terms of the syntax in the HTML source code.

My theory is that because I'm using echo to actually print the link/script object into the HTML, that it's actually not really an object that HTML can recognize? Kind of like trying to echo an object in PHP - it doesnt work.

Any advise?

Comment: Using `echo` shouldn't change anything. Any code / output you can include?

Comment: Maybe the path is wrong .. ? Need code.

Comment: To determine if it's some echo-ey magic, copy and paste the source of a loaded page that doesn't work into its own file and save it as test.html. If test.html works, it's php's fault somehow. Otherwise, you're not outputting the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you use plain HTML of php generated code. For the browser it is all the same.

You need to check your source code, and check if the scripts you include are accessible. So copy/paste the src="blabla" from your source code from your browser, and paste it in the address-bar and see what happens.

It is definitely not PHP's fault.

Comment: Yes, I do think that the path is the problem. I've tried accessing it directly and I'm getting an access denied error - my guess from the .htaccess file. I will check into it.

Comment: That is usually a permission problem. Check the user of the JS files  and the permission (ls -al). Should be readable by nginx (or whatever webserver you use).

Comment: Alright everyone, it was an honest mistake. I realized that my .htaccess file was preventing me access directly to files. All works now.

Thanks for the inputs.